# permutation for large number

Tags: matlab, memory, permutation, largenumber

I am trying to find the permutation for `M=perms([1:26])` but MATLAB can't perform more than `perms(1:10)` as 10 factorial (10!). Do you have any suggestions?

```
clear M Mn 
M=perms([1:10]); 
Mn=zeros(factorial(11),11);

  for i=11 
    m1=factorial(i-1);m2=i-1; 
    for j=1:i
       Mn(m1*j-m1+1:m1*j,1:m2+1)=[ones(m1,1)*j,M];
    end
    M=Mn;
    Mn=[Mn,zeros(factorial(i),1);zeros(factorial(i+1)-factorial(i),i+1)];
end
```

Comment: Can you reformat the code ?

Comment: You do realize that the output of `perms(1:26)`, if it could be computed, would be a 26!-by-26 array of doubles – about 10^29 bytes. What do you actually need to calculate?

Comment: I have a tall  matrix of 26 rows and I want to find all possible rows combination. For example if A is a matrix of 7×3 I will have 7!permutations for rows of A.

Comment: Do you want to actually *make* all the permuted matrices, or do you just want to *count* them? What do you mean by "all possible rows combination"? Maybe post a simple example of exactly what you want to calculate for a 3x3 matrix.